# Erro ao criar array de strings

Tags: c, array, string, gerenciamento-de-memória

Eu estou tendo problemas ao tentar inicializar um vector de *strings* o meu codigo se encontra assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *str[3];
    printf("DIGITE QUALQUER STRING: ");
    scanf("%s", str[0]);
    printf("%s\n", str[0]);
    printf("DIGITE OUTRA STRING: ");
    scanf("%s", str[1]);
    printf("%s\n", str[1]);
    printf("DIGITE MAIS OUTRA: ");
    scanf("%s", str[2]);
    printf("%s\n", str[2]);

    /*
    char *str[2];
    str[0] = "abc";
    str[1] = "cba";
    printf("%s\n", str[0]);
    printf("%s", str[1]);
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Quando eu compilo esse código o compilador não me retorna nenhum aviso e nenhum erro, quando eu o executo e entro com o primeiro valor ele para e sai do programa dai se eu diminuir o meu vetor para apenas 2 e entrar com o primeiro valor ele me retorna lixo de memoria e no segundo me retorna a *string* passada.

Se em vez de vetor eu fizer com apenas `char *str` uma *string* ele me retorna o valor passado normalmente eu estou tentando pegar o macete de alocação dinâmica tenho quase a certeza que eu estou fazendo alguma coisa de errado.

Comment: Você quer alocar a *string* no *stack* ou no *heap*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá erro porque não está alocando espaço para as *strings*, só para seus ponteiros. Então ou muda para *array* e aloca na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) o que me parece mais conveniente para este caso ou use o [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) para alocar no *heap* e retornar um ponteiro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[3][30];
    printf("DIGITE QUALQUER STRING: ");
    scanf("%s", str[0]);
    printf("%s\n", str[0]);
    printf("DIGITE OUTRA STRING: ");
    scanf("%s", str[1]);
    printf("%s\n", str[1]);
    printf("DIGITE MAIS OUTRA: ");
    scanf("%s", str[2]);
    printf("%s\n", str[2]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3K4K8t). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uokahctn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StringStackAllocation.c).

Comment: bom o que eu queria fazer mesmo era criar um array de strings sem tem que usar um limite para o tamanho da string mas eu ja estou vendo que não é uma boa fazer isso. em relação a stack,pilha e alocação eu ainda não eu estou muito familiarizado com isso mas vlw pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

O post é velho, e já tem uma resposta correta, porém, acredito que possa ajudar novos usuários.

Não utilize *`scanf`* para pegar entrada do teclado. Scanf não tem um limite definido, se a entrada do usuário for maior que o espaço alocado, será possível realizar a técnica de buffer overlow.

Eu sugiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_TAMANHO_MAXIMO 30

int main(void) {

        char str[3][BUFFER_TAMANHO_MAXIMO];

        // -1 para incluir o NULL_BYTE \0 no final da string.
        fgets(str[0], BUFFER_TAMANHO_MAXIMO - 1, stdin);        
        puts(str[0]);
        return 0;
}
```